# Can the $L^{\infty}\to L^{\infty}$ norm be bounded by the trace norm?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $k\in C(\mathbb{R}^2; \mathbb{R})$ be a continuous function. Suppose that the operator $K\colon L^2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by the formula 
$$(Kf)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} k(x,y)f(y) dy$$
has a finite trace norm $\|K\|_{tr}$. 
Can we bound the operator norm $\|K\|_{\infty,\infty}$ of $K$ considered as an operator from  $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ to $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ by $c\|K\|_{tr}$, where $c$ is a finite universal constant?

This question was asked by a user and then deleted by the OP while I was preparing the answer. So, I am going to give the answer below.

Comment: Such users are both discourteous and annoying.

Comment: I agree, there are some ups and downs here. Overall, my MathOverflow experience has been useful and exciting to me. I have learned quite a bit from a number of users, including yourself.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no. Indeed, let 
\begin{equation}
 k(x,y):=f(x)g(y),
\end{equation}
where 
$f$ and $g$ are any continuous functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f\ne0$ and $\|g\|_1=\infty$; e.g., one may take $f(x)=g(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. Then 
$K^*Kh=\|f\|_2^2\,(\int gh) g $ for $h\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and hence 
$\|K\|_{tr}=\|f\|_2\|g\|_2<\infty$, whereas 
\begin{equation}
 \|K\|_{\infty,\infty}=\sup_x\int|k(x,y)|dy=\|f\|_\infty \|g\|_1=\infty. 
\end{equation}
So, the inequality $\|K\|_{\infty,\infty}\le c\|K\|_{tr}$ is false for any real $c$.